# How to prepare basic test for TimerService scheduler?

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, schedule

Actually my code works great, unfortunately I found some problems when trying to write integration and unit tests for TimerService without preparing Arquillian container.
My code, simplified:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class GeneralDataExecutor {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    private Timer timer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
            timer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(createScheduleExpression(), createTimerConfig());
        }
    }

    @Timeout
    public void execute() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Any ideas/tips how to get things done?

Comment: *"without preparing Arquillian container"* How exactly are you performing existing integration tests then? The answer depends on that.

Comment: How about creating EJB container?

Comment: Yes, via Arquillian is one way. But you basically said that you aren't using Arquillian. But you also didn't tell what you are using for your existing integration tests. So it's hard to give a suited answer on that. The answer really depends on the integration testing framework which you're actually using. Or do you actually not have any existing integration tests at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are frameworks which help to mock the ejb-container and help to
handle the asynchronity.

Look at the
[Example of a Timer-Bean](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/testing/ioc-unit-test-war/src/main/java/com/oneandone/iocunitejb/ejbs/SingletonTimerEJB.java)

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessTimerEJB extends CountingBean {

   @PostConstruct
   public void postConstruct() {
       setPostConstructCalled();
   }

   @Timeout
   public void callAsynch()  {
       if (isPostConstructCalled()) {
           logcall();
           return;
       } else {
           logger.error("postconstruct did not work for this instance");
       }
   }
}
```

and how it is tested using ioc-unit Asynchronousmanager in

[TestAsynchronousManager](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/testing/ioc-unit-tests5/src/test/java/com/oneandone/ejbcdiunit5/asynchmdb/TestAsynch.java)

Comment: These links are dead.

Comment: Thank you very much, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes of your business functionality it will be sufficient to test your Timeout method ("execute") and have everything else mocked.

You do not need to test the timer functionality, as this is not your code and tested plenty.

Example:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GdeTest{
    @InjectMocks
    GeneralDataExecutor gde = new GeneralDataExecutor();

    @Mock
    TimerService timerService;

     @Test
     void testInitialize() {
     gde.execute();
     //your business assertions here

     //ensure timer initialization
     verify(timerService, times(1)).createCalendarTimer(any(ScheduleExpression.class), 
         any(TimerConfig.class));
     }
}
```